# setCustomValidity is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this javascript that uses `setcustomvalidity`, but there is only one condition that is not working :

```
 $("#newPass").on('invalid',function(){
        var tmp = $('#newPass').val();
        var regex = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]/;
        if(tmp == ""){
          $('#newPass')[0].setCustomValidity('new password is empty');
        }else if(regex.test(tmp)){
            $('#newPass')[0].setCustomValidity('password must be combination of letter and number');
        }else if(tmp.length < 6){
          $('#newPass')[0].setCustomValidity('Password shoult at least 6');
        }else{
          $('#newPass')[0].setCustomValidity('please check your password');
        }
      });
```

it's `regex.test` that is not working, is there any solution to this? maybe the regex is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `regex` variable value to this:

```
var regex = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/;
```

If you test with it, it will return `true` if the string has **at least 1 letter and 1 number**, otherwise `false`.

Comment: but i need regex that must combine between character and number like 'test123'. so if the pass is all number or char, the error message will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

please check this : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Password-Strength-validation-example-using-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx[enter link description here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Password-Strength-validation-example-using-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx)

Comment: var regex = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/;  If you test with it, it will return true if the string has at least 1 letter and 1 number, otherwise return false